# HTML Tidy command-line syntax?

Tags: html, sublimetext3, sublimetext, htmltidy

Why doesn't this work with HTML Tidy?

```
tidy index.html --uppercase-attributes yes
```

(I got the list of available config options from `tidy -help-config` command.)

If I put invalid option there, I get an error, which is good. But if I put a correct option, like the one above, it feels like it's just ignored. The output is always the same and the warnings are the same as well.

I'm trying to use HTML Tidy with Sublime Text 3. I don't expect it to take config with Sublime Text if it doesn't even work from the console.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>HTML Tidy</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input TYPE="text" name="foo">
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I have an input with one attribute lowercased and one attribute uppercased. No matter what I do with `--uppercase-attributes` option, the output is always:

```
Info: Document content looks like HTML5
No warnings or errors were found.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="generator" content=
"HTML Tidy for HTML5 for Apple macOS version 5.6.0">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>HTML Tidy</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="foo">
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm using HTML Tidy 5.6.0 on macOS High Sierra.

Comment: The help option tells you options come **before** filenames: `tidy [option...] [file...]`. This is near-universal convention in both Windows and Linux.

Comment: @smci I know, I answered my own question 3 years ago. But still surprised about no warning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer myself.

Configuration options should go before the name of the file, so instead of this:

```
tidy index.html --uppercase-attributes yes
```

It should be this:

```
tidy --uppercase-attributes yes index.html
```

Not sure why there is no warning or anything though.